# Crash when removeObserver for an Integer property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I create a CustomView:UIView with XIB, load and addObserver for a NSInteger property like that:

//CustomView.h

```
@interface CustomView : UIView
    @property (nonatomic) NSInteger inputStateControl;
@end
```

//CustomView.m

```
static void *kInputStateControlObservingContext = &kInputStateControlObservingContext;
@implementation CustomView
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        //
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)commonInit{
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"inputStateControl" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:kInputStateControlObservingContext];
}

#pragma mark Observer
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if ( context == kInputStateControlObservingContext ) {
        NSInteger oldState = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] integerValue];
        if ( oldState != self.inputStateControl ) {
            NSLog(@"CONTEXT change %i to %i",oldState,self.inputStateControl);
        }
    }
    else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"inputStateControl"];
//    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"inputStateControl" context:kInputStateControlObservingContext];
}

@end
```

Everything work OK if I comment out removeObserver in dealloc, here is the log:

```
CONTEXT change 0 to 2
```

But when removeObserver, App crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <Keyboard 0x6a8bcc0> for the key path "inputStateControl" from <Keyboard 0x6a8bcc0> because it is not registered as an observer.'
```

No crash when comment load CustomView.xib but nothing to do without XIB.
What's wrong in my code?

### How to add and removeObserver for an NSInteger property inside CustomView with Custom Xib?

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT: I add my code to make my question clear. Please help!

https://github.com/lequysang/github_zip/blob/master/CustomViewKVO.zip

Comment: Are you sure `commonInit` is called? Log it.

Comment: Yes, because when comment out removeObserver, observeValueForKeyPath method work with output log in my question.

Comment: You have two calls in dealloc, one commented out. Are you wanting to have both of them in there for some reason? Or is the state of the code as it is crashing?

Comment: I try one of them but no one work.Just try code.

Comment: your init function is odd. there's no need to call '[super init]' since you're overwriting self with the object loaded from the NIB anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what's happening - in your viewDidLoad method, you call `[[CustomView alloc] init]`. This creates a new CustomView instance, and calls `init` on it. However, in `init`, you load a new instance from the nib and replace `self` with the one from the nib. This causes the instance that you created from `alloc` and set up with the `self = [super init];` to be deallocated as there are no more strong references to it. Since this instance is deallocated before calling `commonInit`, it never observes its own properties so removing itself as an observer causes the exception.

One way to fix this would be to just load the view directly from the nib in your view controller, or create a class method on CustomView

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:nil options:nil];
CustomView *customView = topLevelObjects[0];
```

If you do take that approach, discard you `init` implementation and replace it with an `initWithCoder:` that does this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        _inputStateControl = 0;
        [self commonInit];
    }

    return self;
}
```

The reason for implementing `initWithCoder:` is that it will be called automatically when you load the view from the nib. You just have to implement it and you will be able to do the setup that you are already doing in `init`. Also make sure your dealloc is implemented like so:

```
-(void)dealloc{
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"inputStateControl" context:kInputStateControlObservingContext];
}
```

Comment: Thanks!My CustomView is an inputView of UITextView, so I don't know how to use initWithCoder.I'll reply later.

Comment: You shouldn't need to know much - I just edited my question to make this point, but it's just the initializer that gets called when objects are instantiated from nibs. Just make sure it's implemented, and does the same things you were doing in `init` before, and you will be OK.

Comment: Thanks!It work OK. But I still don't understand why must call commonInit both in init and initWithCoder.

Comment: You should delete your implementation of `init` and not use it directly anymore - just load the instance from the nib as shown. If you need to make an instance that's set up in code (rather than a nib) later on, then you can implement `initWithFrame:` and call `commonInit` from there to still have the KVO notifications work. Does that make sense?

Comment: https://github.com/lequysang/github_zip/blob/master/CustomViewKVOnOK.zip I attack OK code base on your answer.I change something but work Only when do like that.Interesting:) Any more comments?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. As far as the code you sent, again, my suggestion is to delete the `init` method of `CustomView`, and delete the `self.customView = [[CustomView alloc] init];` line from `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I miss understand something. Sorry! All OK now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for the opportunity to answer an interesting question!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know *exactly* why what you're doing isn't working, but having an object observe itself like this strikes me as a bad idea.  You should just implement your inputStateControl's setter explicitly (`setInputStateControl`) and do your logging and whatever other side effects you want in that setter method.

Comment: Please check my edit. I've add sample code. Please help me to removeObserver.

Comment: @aăâ I saw your question after the edit and read your code and I'm telling you you're way better off just implementing the setter than making your object observe itself.

Comment: Sorry!I don't understand your suggestion. I'll try another way.

Answer (score 0):

While not an ideal solution by any means, surrounding the remove with a try-catch block will resolve your issue. If in fact the observer is not registered, ignoring an exception during removing it is safe. The main risk is whatever assumption your app is relying on that it IS registered.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're facing the problem.The most short cut way i do is by setting the custom observer to 'nil' in the dealloc ;) ,but in your case to use that shortcut way also you need to add the obeserver in some other way around.

Ok at least i can tell you is,in your dealloc,

```
-(void)dealloc{
    [[NSNotificationCenter default center] removeObserver: self];
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"inputStateControl"];
    //OR
    //If you had create a observer called "temp",then easy way to remove the observer is temp=nil;

}
```

If you're still hanging in,put the @try @catch blocks for the temporary solution,note that its not going to remove the observer ;)...

Not the perfect the answer you were looking for,but its just the way i think...Happy coding :-)